# Wordpress - trying to get image/title of certain categories

Tags: php, wordpress

Okay, so I have these product categories (they are actually categories even though it says just products):

```
$product_one = get_theme_mod('bakes_and_cakes_products_page_one');
$product_two = get_theme_mod('bakes_and_cakes_products_page_two');
$product_three = get_theme_mod('bakes_and_cakes_products_page_three');
$product_four = get_theme_mod('bakes_and_cakes_products_page_four');
$product_five = get_theme_mod('bakes_and_cakes_products_page_five');
```

I'm currently trying this code, which I've created myself based on multiple examples I found online:

```
if($product_one || $product_two || $product_three || $product_four || $product_five) {
            $products_row1 = array( $product_one, $product_two, $product_three, $product_four, $product_five);
            $products_row1 = array_diff( array_unique( $products_row1 ), array('') );
  if($products_row1_qry->have_posts()){
        $count = 0; // column counter
        $rowSize = 4; // max columns per row
        $terms = get_the_terms( 'product_cat', $products_row1);
        foreach ( $terms as $term ){
            $category_name = $term->name;
            $category_thumbnail = get_woocommerce_term_meta($term->term_id, 'thumbnail_id', true);
            $image = wp_get_attachment_url($category_thumbnail);
            # columns display variables 
            $isStartOfNewRow = 0 === ($count % $rowSize); // modulo
            $isEndOfRow = ($count>$rowSize-1  && $isStartOfNewRow);
            $count++;
            if ($isEndOfRow) { ?>
                </div> <?php
            }

            if ($isStartOfNewRow) { ?>
                <div class="row"> <?php
            } ?>
            <div class="col-4">
                <div class="img-holder"> 
                    <img class="category-image" src="<?php echo $image; ?>">
                </div>
                <div class="text">
                    <h3> <?php echo $term ?> </h3>
                    <div class="btn-holder">
                        <a href="/product-category/<?php $term; ?> "> See the Offer!</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div> <?php
        }
        $isStartOfNewRow = 0 === ($count % $rowSize); 
        if ($isStartOfNewRow) { ?>
            </div> <?php
        }
    } ?>
    </div> <?php
 wp_reset_postdata(); 
}
```

And it's not working. My aim is to get those specific product categories that are chosen via the Wordpress theme customiser to display on the home page such that we have four product categories maximum displaying on each row. Obviously this isn't getting the job done well. I don't quite understand how to work with the Woocommerce categories - I tried doing this same thing using a WP_Query and a set of regular WP pages (not Woocommerce stuff) and it worked. Any help is greatly appreciated!